# Aggregate with cbind generating an error

Tags: r

I'm trying to aggregate a bunch of data in a data frame. But the method I'm using is generating the error:

Error in `[.default`(xj, i) : invalid subscript type 'closure'

How can I correct the below code?

Code:

```
agpowerDMWh<-aggregate(cbind(MW, DollarsPerMWh)~Date + HourEnding + DateDateHE + Season + MonthYear + Year + Month + Day + Weekday + IsWorkDayTSX + isPeak + isExtendedPeak + isSuperPeak , data=df, mean, na.rm=TRUE)
```

**Sample data:**

```
    df<-structure(list(DateTime = structure(c(1325402100, 1325403000, 
    1325403900, 1325404800, 1325405700, 1325406600, 1325407500, 1325408400, 
    1325409300, 1325410200, 1325411100, 1325412000, 1325412900, 1325413800, 
    1325414700, 1325415600, 1325416500, 1325417400, 1325418300, 1325419200, 
    1325420100, 1325421000, 1325421900, 1325422800, 1325423700, 1325424600, 
    1325425500, 1325426400, 1325427300, 1325428200, 1325429100, 1325430000, 
    1325430900, 1325431800, 1325432700, 1325433600, 1325434500, 1325435400, 
    1325436300, 1325437200, 1325438100, 1325439000, 1325439900, 1325440800, 
    1325441700, 1325442600, 1325443500, 1325444400), class = c("POSIXct", 
    "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), MW = c(0.75636, 0.73304, 0.75504, 0.74624, 
    0.78628, 0.7832, 0.77176, 0.77968, 0.76516, 0.80168, 0.77, 0.7986, 
    0.77528, 0.7722, 0.78364, 0.77352, 0.72732, 0.75196, 0.73656, 
    0.72336, 0.75064, 0.737, 0.74008, 0.81752, 0.81136, 0.77924, 
    0.79156, 0.79024, 0.78848, 0.78056, 0.79376, 0.76824, 0.8096, 
    0.77, 0.78716, 0.75372, 0.737, 0.72776, 0.7304, 0.7018, 0.69652, 
    0.71192, 0.6952, 0.70752, 0.67804, 0.71808, 0.67584, 0.68904), 
        DollarsPerMWh = c(40.26, 40.26, 40.26, 40.26, 34.936, 34.936, 
        34.936, 34.936, 32.714, 32.714, 32.714, 32.714, 27.346, 27.346, 
        27.346, 27.346, 26.411, 26.411, 26.411, 26.411, 26.4, 26.4, 
        26.4, 26.4, 26.4, 26.4, 26.4, 26.4, 25.927, 25.927, 25.927, 
        25.927, 26.785, 26.785, 26.785, 26.785, 24.464, 24.464, 24.464, 
        24.464, 18.81, 18.81, 18.81, 18.81, 18.315, 18.315, 18.315, 
        18.315), minute = c(15, 30, 45, 0, 15, 30, 45, 0, 15, 30, 
        45, 0, 15, 30, 45, 0, 15, 30, 45, 0, 15, 30, 45, 0, 15, 30, 
        45, 0, 15, 30, 45, 0, 15, 30, 45, 0, 15, 30, 45, 0, 15, 30, 
        45, 0, 15, 30, 45, 0), hour = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 
        2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 
        7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10, 11, 11, 
        11, 11, 12), Date = structure(c(15340, 15340, 15340, 15340, 
        15340, 15340, 15340, 15340, 15340, 15340, 15340, 15340, 15340, 
        15340, 15340, 15340, 15340, 15340, 15340, 15340, 15340, 15340, 
        15340, 15340, 15340, 15340, 15340, 15340, 15340, 15340, 15340, 
        15340, 15340, 15340, 15340, 15340, 15340, 15340, 15340, 15340, 
        15340, 15340, 15340, 15340, 15340, 15340, 15340, 15340), class = "Date"), 
        HourEnding = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 
        4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8, 9, 
        9, 9, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10, 11, 11, 11, 11, 12, 12, 12, 12), 
        DateDateHE = c("2012-01-01 HE1", "2012-01-01 HE1", "2012-01-01 HE1", 
        "2012-01-01 HE1", "2012-01-01 HE2", "2012-01-01 HE2", "2012-01-01 HE2", 
        "2012-01-01 HE2", "2012-01-01 HE3", "2012-01-01 HE3", "2012-01-01 HE3", 
        "2012-01-01 HE3", "2012-01-01 HE4", "2012-01-01 HE4", "2012-01-01 HE4", 
        "2012-01-01 HE4", "2012-01-01 HE5", "2012-01-01 HE5", "2012-01-01 HE5", 
        "2012-01-01 HE5", "2012-01-01 HE6", "2012-01-01 HE6", "2012-01-01 HE6", 
        "2012-01-01 HE6", "2012-01-01 HE7", "2012-01-01 HE7", "2012-01-01 HE7", 
        "2012-01-01 HE7", "2012-01-01 HE8", "2012-01-01 HE8", "2012-01-01 HE8", 
        "2012-01-01 HE8", "2012-01-01 HE9", "2012-01-01 HE9", "2012-01-01 HE9", 
        "2012-01-01 HE9", "2012-01-01 HE10", "2012-01-01 HE10", "2012-01-01 HE10", 
        "2012-01-01 HE10", "2012-01-01 HE11", "2012-01-01 HE11", 
        "2012-01-01 HE11", "2012-01-01 HE11", "2012-01-01 HE12", 
        "2012-01-01 HE12", "2012-01-01 HE12", "2012-01-01 HE12"), 
        Season = c("Winter", "Winter", "Winter", "Winter", "Winter", 
        "Winter", "Winter", "Winter", "Winter", "Winter", "Winter", 
        "Winter", "Winter", "Winter", "Winter", "Winter", "Winter", 
        "Winter", "Winter", "Winter", "Winter", "Winter", "Winter", 
        "Winter", "Winter", "Winter", "Winter", "Winter", "Winter", 
        "Winter", "Winter", "Winter", "Winter", "Winter", "Winter", 
        "Winter", "Winter", "Winter", "Winter", "Winter", "Winter", 
        "Winter", "Winter", "Winter", "Winter", "Winter", "Winter", 
        "Winter"), MonthYear = structure(c(2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 
        2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 
        2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 
        2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 
        2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 
        2012, 2012, 2012, 2012), class = "yearmon"), Year = c(2012, 
        2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 
        2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 
        2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 
        2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 
        2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012), Month = c(1, 1, 
        1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
        1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
        1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), Day = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
        1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
        1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
        1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), Weekday = c("Sunday", 
        "Sunday", "Sunday", "Sunday", "Sunday", "Sunday", "Sunday", 
        "Sunday", "Sunday", "Sunday", "Sunday", "Sunday", "Sunday", 
        "Sunday", "Sunday", "Sunday", "Sunday", "Sunday", "Sunday", 
        "Sunday", "Sunday", "Sunday", "Sunday", "Sunday", "Sunday", 
        "Sunday", "Sunday", "Sunday", "Sunday", "Sunday", "Sunday", 
        "Sunday", "Sunday", "Sunday", "Sunday", "Sunday", "Sunday", 
        "Sunday", "Sunday", "Sunday", "Sunday", "Sunday", "Sunday", 
        "Sunday", "Sunday", "Sunday", "Sunday", "Sunday"), IsWorkDayTSX = c(FALSE, 
        FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
        FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
        FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
        FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
        FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
        FALSE, FALSE), isPeak = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), isExtendedPeak = c(0, 
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
        1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), isSuperPeak = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), .Names = c("DateTime", "MW", "DollarsPerMWh", 
    "minute", "hour", "Date", "HourEnding", "DateDateHE", "Season", 
    "MonthYear", "Year", "Month", "Day", "Weekday", "IsWorkDayTSX", 
    "isPeak", "isExtendedPeak", "isSuperPeak"), row.names = c(NA, 
    48L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1):

For me it is working:

```
df<-structure(
list(
DateTime = structure(c(1325402100, 1325403000, 1325403900, 1325404800, 1325405700, 1325406600, 1325407500, 1325408400, 1325409300, 1325410200, 1325411100, 1325412000, 1325412900, 1325413800, 1325414700, 1325415600, 1325416500, 1325417400, 1325418300, 1325419200, 1325420100, 1325421000, 1325421900, 1325422800, 1325423700, 1325424600, 1325425500, 1325426400, 1325427300, 1325428200, 1325429100, 1325430000, 1325430900, 1325431800, 1325432700, 1325433600, 1325434500, 1325435400, 1325436300, 1325437200, 1325438100, 1325439000, 1325439900, 1325440800, 1325441700, 1325442600, 1325443500, 1325444400), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), 
MW = c(0.75636, 0.73304, 0.75504, 0.74624, 0.78628, 0.7832, 0.77176, 0.77968, 0.76516, 0.80168, 0.77, 0.7986, 0.77528, 0.7722, 0.78364, 0.77352, 0.72732, 0.75196, 0.73656, 0.72336, 0.75064, 0.737, 0.74008, 0.81752, 0.81136, 0.77924, 0.79156, 0.79024, 0.78848, 0.78056, 0.79376, 0.76824, 0.8096, 0.77, 0.78716, 0.75372, 0.737, 0.72776, 0.7304, 0.7018, 0.69652, 0.71192, 0.6952, 0.70752, 0.67804, 0.71808, 0.67584, 0.68904), 
DollarsPerMWh = c(40.26, 40.26, 40.26, 40.26, 34.936, 34.936, 34.936, 34.936, 32.714, 32.714, 32.714, 32.714, 27.346, 27.346, 27.346, 27.346, 26.411, 26.411, 26.411, 26.411, 26.4, 26.4, 26.4, 26.4, 26.4, 26.4, 26.4, 26.4, 25.927, 25.927, 25.927, 25.927, 26.785, 26.785, 26.785, 26.785, 24.464, 24.464, 24.464, 24.464, 18.81, 18.81, 18.81, 18.81, 18.315, 18.315, 18.315, 18.315), 
minute = c(15, 30, 45, 0, 15, 30, 45, 0, 15, 30, 45, 0, 15, 30, 45, 0, 15, 30, 45, 0, 15, 30, 45, 0, 15, 30, 45, 0, 15, 30, 45, 0, 15, 30, 45, 0, 15, 30, 45, 0, 15, 30, 45, 0, 15, 30, 45, 0), 
hour = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10, 11, 11, 11, 11, 12), 
Date = structure(c(15340, 15340, 15340, 15340, 15340, 15340, 15340, 15340, 15340, 15340, 15340, 15340, 15340, 15340, 15340, 15340, 15340, 15340, 15340, 15340, 15340, 15340, 15340, 15340, 15340, 15340, 15340, 15340, 15340, 15340, 15340, 15340, 15340, 15340, 15340, 15340, 15340, 15340, 15340, 15340, 15340, 15340, 15340, 15340, 15340, 15340, 15340, 15340), class = "Date"), 
HourEnding = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10, 11, 11, 11, 11, 12, 12, 12, 12), 
DateDateHE = c("2012-01-01 HE1", "2012-01-01 HE1", "2012-01-01 HE1", "2012-01-01 HE1", "2012-01-01 HE2", "2012-01-01 HE2", "2012-01-01 HE2", "2012-01-01 HE2", "2012-01-01 HE3", "2012-01-01 HE3", "2012-01-01 HE3", "2012-01-01 HE3", "2012-01-01 HE4", "2012-01-01 HE4", "2012-01-01 HE4", "2012-01-01 HE4", "2012-01-01 HE5", "2012-01-01 HE5", "2012-01-01 HE5", "2012-01-01 HE5", "2012-01-01 HE6", "2012-01-01 HE6", "2012-01-01 HE6", "2012-01-01 HE6", "2012-01-01 HE7", "2012-01-01 HE7", "2012-01-01 HE7", "2012-01-01 HE7", "2012-01-01 HE8", "2012-01-01 HE8", "2012-01-01 HE8", "2012-01-01 HE8", "2012-01-01 HE9", "2012-01-01 HE9", "2012-01-01 HE9", "2012-01-01 HE9", "2012-01-01 HE10", "2012-01-01 HE10", "2012-01-01 HE10", "2012-01-01 HE10", "2012-01-01 HE11", "2012-01-01 HE11", "2012-01-01 HE11", "2012-01-01 HE11", "2012-01-01 HE12", "2012-01-01 HE12", "2012-01-01 HE12", "2012-01-01 HE12"), 
Season = c("Winter", "Winter", "Winter", "Winter", "Winter", "Winter", "Winter", "Winter", "Winter", "Winter", "Winter", "Winter", "Winter", "Winter", "Winter", "Winter", "Winter", "Winter", "Winter", "Winter", "Winter", "Winter", "Winter", "Winter", "Winter", "Winter", "Winter", "Winter", "Winter", "Winter", "Winter", "Winter", "Winter", "Winter", "Winter", "Winter", "Winter", "Winter", "Winter", "Winter", "Winter", "Winter", "Winter", "Winter", "Winter", "Winter", "Winter", "Winter"), 
MonthYear = structure(c(2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012), class = "yearmon"), Year = c(2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012), 
Month = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), 
Day = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), 
Weekday = c("Sunday", "Sunday", "Sunday", "Sunday", "Sunday", "Sunday", "Sunday", "Sunday", "Sunday", "Sunday", "Sunday", "Sunday", "Sunday", "Sunday", "Sunday", "Sunday", "Sunday", "Sunday", "Sunday", "Sunday", "Sunday", "Sunday", "Sunday", "Sunday", "Sunday", "Sunday", "Sunday", "Sunday", "Sunday", "Sunday", "Sunday", "Sunday", "Sunday", "Sunday", "Sunday", "Sunday", "Sunday", "Sunday", "Sunday", "Sunday", "Sunday", "Sunday", "Sunday", "Sunday", "Sunday", "Sunday", "Sunday", "Sunday"), 
IsWorkDayTSX = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE), 
isPeak = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), 
isExtendedPeak = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), 
isSuperPeak = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
), 
.Names = c("DateTime", "MW", "DollarsPerMWh", "minute", "hour", "Date", "HourEnding", "DateDateHE", "Season", "MonthYear", "Year", "Month", "Day", "Weekday", "IsWorkDayTSX", "isPeak", "isExtendedPeak", "isSuperPeak"), 
row.names = c(NA, 48L), class = "data.frame")


agpowerDMWh<-aggregate(
cbind(MW, DollarsPerMWh)~Date + 
HourEnding + 
DateDateHE + 
Season + 
MonthYear + 
Year + 
Month + 
Day + 
Weekday + 
IsWorkDayTSX + 
isPeak + 
isExtendedPeak + 
isSuperPeak , 
data=df, mean, na.rm=TRUE)
```

gives

```
|Date       | HourEnding|DateDateHE      |Season | MonthYear| Year| Month| Day|Weekday |IsWorkDayTSX | isPeak| isExtendedPeak| isSuperPeak|      MW| DollarsPerMWh|
|:----------|----------:|:---------------|:------|---------:|----:|-----:|---:|:-------|:------------|------:|--------------:|-----------:|-------:|-------------:|
|2012-01-01 |          1|2012-01-01 HE1  |Winter |      2012| 2012|     1|   1|Sunday  |FALSE        |      0|              0|           0| 0.74767|        40.260|
|2012-01-01 |          2|2012-01-01 HE2  |Winter |      2012| 2012|     1|   1|Sunday  |FALSE        |      0|              0|           0| 0.78023|        34.936|
|2012-01-01 |          3|2012-01-01 HE3  |Winter |      2012| 2012|     1|   1|Sunday  |FALSE        |      0|              0|           0| 0.78386|        32.714|
|2012-01-01 |          4|2012-01-01 HE4  |Winter |      2012| 2012|     1|   1|Sunday  |FALSE        |      0|              0|           0| 0.77616|        27.346|
|2012-01-01 |          5|2012-01-01 HE5  |Winter |      2012| 2012|     1|   1|Sunday  |FALSE        |      0|              0|           0| 0.73480|        26.411|
|2012-01-01 |          6|2012-01-01 HE6  |Winter |      2012| 2012|     1|   1|Sunday  |FALSE        |      0|              0|           0| 0.76131|        26.400|
|2012-01-01 |          7|2012-01-01 HE7  |Winter |      2012| 2012|     1|   1|Sunday  |FALSE        |      0|              0|           0| 0.79310|        26.400|
|2012-01-01 |         10|2012-01-01 HE10 |Winter |      2012| 2012|     1|   1|Sunday  |FALSE        |      0|              1|           0| 0.72424|        24.464|
|2012-01-01 |         11|2012-01-01 HE11 |Winter |      2012| 2012|     1|   1|Sunday  |FALSE        |      0|              1|           0| 0.70279|        18.810|
|2012-01-01 |         12|2012-01-01 HE12 |Winter |      2012| 2012|     1|   1|Sunday  |FALSE        |      0|              1|           0| 0.69025|        18.315|
|2012-01-01 |          8|2012-01-01 HE8  |Winter |      2012| 2012|     1|   1|Sunday  |FALSE        |      0|              1|           0| 0.78276|        25.927|
|2012-01-01 |          9|2012-01-01 HE9  |Winter |      2012| 2012|     1|   1|Sunday  |FALSE        |      0|              1|           0| 0.78012|        26.785|
```

Comment: Thanks for checking for me. I wondering why I'm getting an error.